# Error with translations while following "Get Started" tutorial

Tags: development

I was following along with [the "Getting Started" tutorial](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started), and when I got to [the step to add translations](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#Adding-Translations), my project started failing to compile. I can't make sense of the error.

It would be really handy if there were a Github repo (or something) with working code and tagged commits that follow along with the tutorial. Does such a thing exist?

If not, then I need your help! The error I'm getting is this:

```
$ ninja
[0/1] Regenerating build files.
The Meson build system
Version: 0.48.0
Source dir: /home/nathan/projects/fanboy
Build dir: /home/nathan/projects/fanboy/build
Build type: native build
Project name: com.github.nwallace.fanboy
Project version: undefined
Native C compiler: cc (gcc 8.2.1 "cc (GCC) 8.2.1 20180831")
Native Vala compiler: valac (valac 0.42.2)
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Dependency gtk+-3.0 found: YES (cached)
Build targets in project: 5
Found ninja-1.8.2 at /usr/bin/ninja
[3/4] Compiling C object 'com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/meson-generated_src_Application.c.o'.
FAILED: com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/meson-generated_src_Application.c.o 
cc -Icom.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -w -g -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=com.github.nwallace.fanboy -pthread  -MD -MQ 'com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/meson-generated_src_Application.c.o' -MF 'com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/meson-generated_src_Application.c.o.d' -o 'com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/meson-generated_src_Application.c.o' -c 'com.github.nwallace.fanboy@exe/src/Application.c'
../src/Application.vala: In function ‘__lambda4_’:
<command-line>: error: ‘com’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h:30:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETTEXT_PACKAGE’
 #define  _(String) ((char *) g_dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, String))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Application.vala:35:47: note: in expansion of macro ‘_’
       hello_button.label = _("Hello World!");
                                               ^
<command-line>: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h:30:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETTEXT_PACKAGE’
 #define  _(String) ((char *) g_dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, String))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Application.vala:35:47: note: in expansion of macro ‘_’
       hello_button.label = _("Hello World!");
                                               ^
../src/Application.vala: In function ‘my_app_real_activate’:
<command-line>: error: ‘com’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h:30:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETTEXT_PACKAGE’
 #define  _(String) ((char *) g_dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, String))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Application.vala:32:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘_’
     var hello_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label(_("Click me!"));
                                                   ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

#### You can see the full project source on my Github. Here's a link to the relevant commit that broke things: https://github.com/nwallace/fanboy/compare/add-translations

Some relevant files copy/pasted here for ease/future reference:

**src/Application.vala**:

```
class MyApp : Gtk.Application {
  public MyApp() {
    Object(
      application_id: "com.github.nwallace.fanboy",
      flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
    );
  }

  protected override void activate() {
    var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(this);
    var hello_button = new Gtk.Button.with_label(_("Click me!"));
    hello_button.margin = 12;
    hello_button.clicked.connect(() => {
      hello_button.label = _("Hello World!");
      hello_button.sensitive = false;
    });
    window.set_title(_("Welcome to GNOME"));
    window.set_default_size(300, 300);
    window.add(hello_button);
    window.show_all();
  }
}

public int main(string[] args) {
  return new MyApp().run(args);
}
```

**meson.build**:

```
# project name and programming language
project('com.github.nwallace.fanboy', 'vala', 'c')

i18n = import('i18n')

add_global_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=@0@'.format(meson.project_name()), language:'c')

# Create a new executable, list the files we want to compile, list the dependencies we need, and install
executable(
  meson.project_name(),
  'src/Application.vala',
  dependencies: [
    dependency('gtk+-3.0')
  ],
  install: true
)

# Translate and install our .desktop file
i18n.merge_file(
  input: join_paths('data', meson.project_name() + '.desktop.in'),
  output: meson.project_name() + '.desktop',
  po_dir: join_paths(meson.source_root(), 'po'),
  type: 'desktop',
  install: true,
  install_dir: join_paths(get_option('datadir'), 'applications')
)

subdir('po')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your `meson.build` file is that some parenthesis are missing:

```
add_global_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=@0@'.format(meson.project_name()), language:'c')
```

should be

```
add_global_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="@0@"'.format(meson.project_name()), language:'c')
```

Notice: `"@0@"`.
The `format` function will replace this with `com.github.nwallace.fanboy` because that is your project name.

Consider what happens, when the macro `_` gets expanded.
This is the relevant error from your log:

```
error: ‘com’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h:30:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETTEXT_PACKAGE’
```

The macro is defined as:

```
#define  _(String) ((char *) g_dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, String))
```

When `GETTEXT_PACKAGE=com.github.nwallace.fanboy` the macro expands to:

```
(String) ((char *) g_dgettext (com.github.nwallace.fanboy, String))
```

Remember that Vala compiles down to C code and that is what the macro is expanding to. The function `g_dgettext` however expects a String as first argument. Because `com.github.nwallace.fanboy` is incidentally valid C syntax, you get the `error: ‘com’ undeclared`.

The solution is to wrap the name of your project with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

This one was difficult for me to solve on my own project. But here's what I've found. GETTEXT_PACKAGE **really** hates `\`.

To resolve this issue I had to go through each of my PO files and remove the \n in each string.

So.
`"Project-Id-Version: org.pantheon.dexter-contacts\n"`
Became
`"Project-Id-Version: org.pantheon.dexter-contacts"`

In addition to this I had to fix my meson.build
`add_global_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=\"@0@"\'.format (meson.project_name()), language:'c')`

became

`add_global_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="@0@"'.format (meson.project_name()), language:'c')`

I noticed in your PO files you still have \n. I'd recommend removing those!

Comment: "\n" in PO files are no problem. A correct `add_global_arguments` is what fixed the issue.